# Combining two elasticsearch queries

Tags: elasticsearch

Thanks to the fantastic Kibana frontend for my elasticsearch indexes, I'm able to construct a query to pull an hour-by-hour count of records over a specific timespan:

```
  {
  "facets": {
    "0": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "@timestamp",
        "interval": "1h"
      },
      "global": true,
      "facet_filter": {
        "fquery": {
          "query": {
            "filtered": {
              "query": {
                "query_string": {
                  "query": "*"
                }
              },
              "filter": {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                    {
                      "range": {
                        "@timestamp": {
                          "from": "2014-08-01T07:00:00.000Z",
                          "to": "2014-09-01T06:59:59.999Z"
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "fquery": {
                        "query": {
                          "query_string": {
                            "query": "tags:\"solr_search\""
                          }
                        },
                        "_cache": true
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0
}'
```

Which gives me output like:

```
{
  "took" : 27,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 155,
    "successful" : 155,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 267366,
    "max_score" : 0.0,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "facets" : {
    "0" : {
      "_type" : "date_histogram",
      "entries" : [ {
        "time" : 1406876400000,
        "count" : 120
      }, {
        "time" : 1406880000000,
        "count" : 115
      }, {
        "time" : 1406883600000,
        "count" : 134
      }, {
        "time" : 1406887200000,
        "count" : 87
      }, {
        "time" : 1406890800000,
        "count" : 99
      }, {
        "time" : 1406894400000,
        "count" : 141
      }, {
        "time" : 1406898000000,
        "count" : 168
      }, {
        "time" : 1406901600000,
        "count" : 300
      }, {
        "time" : 1406905200000,
        "count" : 782
      }, {
        "time" : 1406908800000,
        "count" : 1085
      }, {
```

And (using Kibana's help again) I can, for one specific time bucket, get a top 10 list of the most searched terms with a query like this:

```
{
  "facets": {
    "terms": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "searchstring.raw",
        "size": 10,
        "order": "count",
        "exclude": []
      },
      "facet_filter": {
        "fquery": {
          "query": {
            "filtered": {
              "query": {
                "bool": {
                  "should": [
                    {
                      "query_string": {
                        "query": "*"
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              "filter": {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                    {
                      "range": {
                        "@timestamp": {
                          "from": 1406876400000,
                          "to": 1406880000000
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "fquery": {
                        "query": {
                          "query_string": {
                            "query": "tags:\"solr_search\""
                          }
                        },
                        "_cache": true
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0
}'
```

Which gives results like this:

```
{
  "took" : 56,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 155,
    "successful" : 155,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 267366,
    "max_score" : 0.0,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "facets" : {
    "terms" : {
      "_type" : "terms",
      "missing" : 0,
      "total" : 120,
      "other" : 86,
      "terms" : [ {
        "term" : "term1",
        "count" : 11
      }, {
        "term" : "term2",
        "count" : 4
      }, {
        "term" : "term3",
        "count" : 3
      }, {
        "term" : "term4",
        "count" : 3
      }, {
        "term" : "term5",
        "count" : 3
      }, {
        "term" : "term6",
        "count" : 2
      }, {
        "term" : "term7",
        "count" : 2
      }, {
        "term" : "term8",
        "count" : 2
      }, {
        "term" : "term9",
        "count" : 2
      }, {
        "term" : "term10",
        "count" : 2
      } ]
    }
  }
}
```

What I would like to do is: **for each time bucket in the first query's output pull the top 10 terms for that time bucket and put that in the output for each time bucket**.  I'm still fairly new to the elasticsearch query language and my attempts so far at merging the two queries have gone down in flames.  If anyone has any pointers I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up ditching the facets approach for the newer aggregations syntax.  Here's what eventually returned what I was looking for:

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "range": {
                                "@timestamp": {
                                    "from": "2014-08-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                                    "to":   "2014-09-01T00:00:00.000Z"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "fquery": {
                                "query": {
                                    "query_string": {
                                        "query": "tags:\"solr_search\""
                                    }
                                },
                                "_cache": true
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "searches_per_hour": {
            "date_histogram" : {
                "field": "@timestamp",
                "interval": "1h",
                "format": "yyyy-MM-dd ha"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "top_search_terms": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "searchstring.raw",
                        "size": 10,
                        "shard_size": 300
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe this will shorten someone else's work day in the future :)